# Handling POST requests with Symofny Forms in FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle

It's not clear to me how I should use the Symfony Form Component with FOSRestBundle for POST endpoints that I use to create resources.

Here is what I've got in my POST controller action:

```
//GuestController.php
public function cpostAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $entity = new Guest();
    $form = $this->createForm(GuestType::class, $entity);

    $form->submit($data);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $dm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dm->persist($entity);
        $dm->flush();

        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

What I do is:

1. Send an `application/json` POST request to the endpoint (`/guests`);
2. Create a form instance that binds to an entity (`Guest`);
3. Due to the fact that I'm sending JSON, I need to `json_decode` the request body before submitting it to the form (`$form->submit($data)`).

**The questions I have:**

1. Do I really always have to `json_decode()` the `Request` content manually before submitting it to a Form? Can this process be somehow automated with FosRestBundle?
2. Is it possible to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data to the controller action and have it handled with:

-

```
$form->handleRequest($request)
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
...
```

I couldn't get the above to work, the form instance was never submitted.

3. Is there any advantage of using the Form Component over using a `ParamConverter` together with the validator directly - here is the idea:

-

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("guest", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
*/
public function cpostAction(Guest $guest)
{
    $violations = $this->getValidator()->validate($guest);

    if ($violations->count()) {
        return $this->view($violations, Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $this->persistAndFlush($guest);

    return ....;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/rest-api-in-symfony-3-1/) article can help you.

Comment: In my opinion it's related to your fos_rest config. Could you share it here ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing to you and it's difficult to find some answers for this subject. I think today it's an important subject to develop website with api rest for mobile apps. Anyway!

Please find my answer below:

> > Do I really always have to json_decode() the Request content manually before submitting it to a Form?

No, i get data like this
$params = $request->query->all();
$user->setUsername($params['fos_user_registration_form']['username']);

> > Can this process be somehow automated with FosRestBundle?

I don't think so.

> > Is it possible to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded data to the controller action and have it handled with

Yes, but i'm currently trying to handle my form like that and I can not do it.

> Is there any advantage of using the Form Component over using a ParamConverter together with the validator directly - here is the idea:

No

I'm guessing if I'm not going to only register the user with:
       $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

and make my control manually.

I posted an issue here and i'm waiting:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2405

did you manage to get further information ?